# How can I block some characters in a textarea with VueJs?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, textarea

I have a textarea for sending messages and I wanna block emails and site links. So when I write an `@`  or `https://` there must be error messages shown, using v-if, but how can I do this? Which functions?

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
   message: {
     content: ""
    }
  },
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
 <div>
 <textarea v-bind="message" v-model="message.content" cols="30" rows="10">
   
 </textarea>
 
 <p v-if="message.content == '@'">
   No special characters
 </p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: post your code. You will need to write the function yourself. Vue itself does not provide such function.

Comment: i post my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check by regex type , for your condition `var regex = /(@|https)/g;` . Also set `hasError` data for message display control and you can use `vue watch` for your data changing (message.content)

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
   message: {
     content: ""
    },
    hasError: false
  },
  watch: {
    'message.content': function(newVal,oldVal) {
       var regex = /(@|https)/g;
       this.hasError = newVal.match(regex);
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
 <div>
 <textarea v-bind="message" v-model="message.content" cols="30" rows="5">
   
 </textarea>
 
 <p v-if="hasError">
   No special characters
 </p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you should add method @change or @input to textarea, and then test for everything using regex and than replace it or whatever you want to do